# Error: SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object line 1 character 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, magento

We have built a Magento Community 1.7.0.1 template  that is fully based on jQuery mobile v1.2.0. It also loads the regular jQuery library version 1.8.2.

Everything works fine in every browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, ...) except in Internet Explorer the following error is showing in the console:

> SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object
>
> index, line 1 character 1

We have been searching on how to fix this issue but haven't found any solution. The same error appears on both IE8 and IE9. We have tried removing all add-ons, accelerators, ... and the issue still persists.

The following is code is located on line 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

**EDIT1:** Weird thing is, if I start up developer tools in IE and under the script tab click on "Start debugging" the error goes way when I refresh the page. When I click on "Stop debugging" and refresh the page, the error still DOES NOT show. Weirdest thing ever...

Has any of you come across this issue already? Any idea how I can go around to debug/solve this?

Answer (score 1):

After debugging a bit more I found out that the following code was causing the issue:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(scrollTo, 0, 0, 1)">
```

Simply remove that and it will work again ;)